# Где можно скачать библиотеку winsock2?

Tags: c, winsock, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно скачать библиотеку `winsock2`? Eже всё облазила, найти не могу...

Comment: А на вашем компьютере её нет? Вопрос не вызвал бы удивления, если бы у Вас был windows 3.1 или около

Comment: @Дарьялла то, что там pas и inc означает, что ссылка для Delfi или Paskal :) Поэтому мой ответ был неверен.

Comment: @alexlz, а где это может быть?.. я нигде не нашла и vs не находит

Comment: Эта библиотека вообще лежит в `%WINDOWS%/system32/WINSOCK.dll`  
[ссылка](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23842722/WINSOCK.DLL) для Win7x32 на случай, если у Вас ее нет.

Comment: @ReinRaus, и куда мне нужно её скопировать, чтобы visual studio его видела?.. поместила в ../lib, пишет, что не может найти.

Comment: Если delphi, то у unit'ов там другие расширения, какие -- не помню.
Попробуйте посмотреть help для функций socket, accept, connect, bind.
В visual studio, если Вы пишите на с/с++ оно наверняка есть, только вот .lib и .dll -- вещи разные. Ну и не забывайте про хедерфайлы (подключаются оператором препроцессора #include). Как называется и где лежит -- не скажу, у меня нет MS VS

Comment: @Дарьялла, не знаю как в MS VS (я с ней не знаком), а в MinGW gcc надо вызывать с флагами  -lws2_32 -lwsock32. Библиотеку из system32/ никуда копировать не надо. Среди "системных" .h файлов должен быть winsock2.h и подключаемые из него .h

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтоп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если создаешь проект в mfc то в диалоге проекта на вкладке Advanced Features ставишь галочку на Windows sockets, все, теперь будет видеть (хотя нигде потом в свойствах проекта никогда не находил пункта, что лункует, но если не поставить - будет ругаться). Здесь речь идет о семерке, наверно в старших версиях аналогично...

А если же делаешь в чистых Win32, то в свойствах проекта заходишь Linker-Input и в графе AdditonalDependencies пишешь WSOCK32.LIB

Answer (score 2):

*В коде:*

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
```

*В Visual Studio:*

Project => Имя_проекта Properties (Alt + F7) => Configuration Properties => Linker => Command Line: дописываем **`ws2_32.lib`**

Так дело обстоит в Visual Studio 2010.