# Не удается открыть файл включение: winsock2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

Win7 x64

MS VS 2010 Ultimate

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
```

Если честно даже не знаю что добавить...

Comment: Библиотека сама есть? Путь к ней указан?

Comment: Посмотрите - у вас Windows SDK установлен?

Comment: Дубль: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/113412

Comment: Это не дубль, так как в том вопросе спрашивают о библиотечном файле, инклуд там имеется, там не было линковки. Тут же `#include` не работает.

Comment: тот же проект в другой студии компилируется без проблем.